# Misma consulta con diferentes tiempos de respuesta

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

Tengo una consulta **Primera version** de mi código, donde recupero datos de diferentes tablas con INNER JOIN.

```
        $output = array('data' => array());
        $query = $con->query("SELECT ticket.PK_idTicket, ticket.tituloTicket, ticket.descripcionTicket, ticket.actualizado, ticket.statusTicket, ticket.prioridadTicket, ticket.refTicket, subcategoria.subcategoriaDesc, categoria.categoriaDesc FROM ticket INNER JOIN subcategoria ON ticket.FK_idSubcategoria = subcategoria.PK_idSubcategoria INNER JOIN categoria ON subcategoria.FK_idCategoria = categoria.PK_idCategoria WHERE ticket.statusTicket = 4 ORDER BY actualizado DESC");

        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            //Almacenar datos en array
        }
        // retornar los datos.
        echo json_encode($output);
```

Ahora modificando un poco el código, uso PDO para recuperar los datos.

```
      public static function ticketsEstatusAdminModel($id){

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT ticket.PK_idTicket, ticket.tituloTicket, ticket.descripcionTicket,ticket.actualizado, ticket.statusTicket, ticket.prioridadTicket, ticket.refTicket, subcategoria.subcategoriaDesc, categoria.categoriaDesc FROM ticket INNER JOIN subcategoria ON ticket.FK_idSubcategoria = subcategoria.PK_idSubcategoria INNER JOIN categoria ON subcategoria.FK_idCategoria = categoria.PK_idCategoria WHERE ticket.statusTicket = :estatus ORDER BY actualizado DESC");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":estatus", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

            $stmt -> close();
        }
```

/// CONTROLADOR

```
public static function ticketsCerradosAdminController(){
        // recuperar datos.
        $respuesta = TicketsModels::ticketsEstatusAdminModel(4);   


        foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item){              

            //  Almacenar los datos en el arreglo.

        }
       // retornar datos.
        return $datos;
    }
```

El cambio que he realizado es pasar un parámetro para usar la misma consulta en varias vistas.

Con este cambio me surge el problema de que la segunda consulta (Con PDO) se tarda unas 3 veces más en ejecutar que la primera, no entiendo a que se deba, ojala me pudieran orientar.

Comment: Tal vez si le agregas un `EXPLAIN` a cada una de las consultas editando tu pregunta y agregando los resultados se pueda saber de forma mas exacta el por que

Comment: Creo que el problema del porqué tu consulta tarda más con PDO pueda deberse a los procesos internos que tu servidor realice para trabajar con PDO, el tiempo de respuesta, por cierto, que tu motor de base de datos tarde en ejecutar es muy diferente al cual el servidor tarde en procesar. Me parece que no conoces esta diferencia y por eso tal vez crees que es lo mismo, pero no lo es.

Comment: Los códigos no son para nada iguales. En el código PDO estás usando `fetchAll`. No sé cuántas filas traerá la consulta, pero `fetchAll` no se recomienda cuando son muchos datos, es mejor usar `fetch`, abrir un `while` e ir metiendo los datos en un array (justo como haces en la versión 1). Desde ahí mismo puedes devolver un JSON. Otra diferencia es que en la versión 2 lees los datos en un bucle cuando se recibe la respuesta. Otra cosa, el `close` que tienes después del `return` no se ejecuta nunca. Cuando una función encuentra `return` ... pues eso, retorna y no vuelve a las líneas siguientes.